# Handling password confirmations on spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing an user crud in spring-mvc.

My model has the following properties:

```
private Long id;
private String password;
private String username;
private Collection<Authority> myAuthorities;
private boolean isAccountNonExpired;
private boolean isAccountNonLocked;
private boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
private boolean isEnabled;
```

I solved how to show the `Authority` class in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498193/spring-mvc-3-0-crud-with-checkboxes-issue).

Now I am willing my form to be able to have a second password field to confirm that the user typed the password correctly.

I don't want to add a `confirmPassword` property to the model, so my question is how to fix this the best way possible.

Edit:

Everything is working with axtavt's answer but I am missing a way to validate.
I have the following method in my controller, but even though I place a `@Validate`
`ApplicationUserFormValidator` isn't called.

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView create(Model model,
   @Valid @ModelAttribute ApplicationUserForm applicationUserFrom,
   BindingResult result) {
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

  if (result.hasErrors()) {
   modelAndView.setViewName(USER_CREATE_FORM);
  } else {
   modelAndView.setViewName(REDIRECT_TO_USER_LIST);
   modelAndView.addObject(USER_FORM_MESSAGE, USER_FORM_ADD_SUCCESSFUL);
   applicationUserService.save(applicationUserFrom.getUser);
  }

  return modelAndView;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an enclosing object to keep a confirmation:

```
public class ApplicationUserForm {
    private ApplicationUser user;
    private String confirmPassword;

    ...
}
```

-

```
Password: <form:password path = "user.password" />
Confirm password: <form:password path = "confirmPassword" />
```

Validator also works fine:

```
public class ApplicationUserFormValidator implements Validator {
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ApplicationUserForm f = (ApplicationUserForm) target;

        if (!f.getConfirmPassword().equals(f.getUser().getPassword())) ...

        errors.pushNestedPath("user");
        new ApplicationUserValidator().validate(f.getUser(), errors);
        errors.popNestedPath();
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** If you use `@Valid` annotation, you need to register a validator using `@InitBinder` or in the config as described in the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-configuring). You may also use a fully declarative JSR-303-style validation, but i'm not sure how will it play with business constraints such as `user.password == confirmPassword`.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder b) {
    b.setValidator(new ApplicationUserFormValidator());
}
```

Comment: The first part went great, but I just edit my question adding an issue with validation.
Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Cool, I found that in the docs while looking for the solution, but if I do that I lose the JSR-303 annotations in my model.

For instance, my model has: @NotNull
 @Size(min = 6, max = 12)
 private String username;

Comment: @Macarse: Then you need a JSR-303's `ConstraintValidator` instead of Spring's `Validator`: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints

Answer (score 6):

add **confirmPassword** in your applicationUserFrom class
and add check function in setter
it's my best way

```
private String password;
@NotNull(message="not match")
private String confirmPassword;

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    checkPassword();//check
}   

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    checkPassword();//check
}

private void checkPassword() {
    if(this.password == null || this.confirmPassword == null){
        return;
    }else if(!this.password.equals(confirmPassword)){
        this.confirmPassword = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to do like this.

```java
@NotNull(message="not match")
@Transient
private String confirmPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I dealt with this was to put password confirmation and "are you sure you want to do this?" confirmation into the the access policy object that implemented fine-grained access control rules in the controller.

Rather than implementing user management all from scratch, you could use an off-the-shelf solution; e.g. [Emmet](http://metadata.net/sites/emmet-0.4-SNAPSHOT/).  (Disclaimer - I'm the author.)

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself correctly.
I need my form to have a second field for the password. Something like:

Password:
Confirm password:

And then use a validator to check that passwords are equal.